# Odoo 10 selection field after save error

Tags: field, odoo-10

I have a selection field and this function for list items in field by dynamically.

```py
def get_years(self):
        year_list = []
        year = date.today().year+1
        lastyear = date.today().year - 20
        for i in range(int(lastyear),int(year)):
            year_list.append((i, str(i)))
        return year_list
```

this is the field,

```py
year = fields.Selection(get_years, string='Yıl', default=get_current_year, restore="True")
```

and when I save the form, this field becomes unknown. I found what is the problem but I don't know the solution. Problem is compute function, when i write items like [(1997,1997),(2016,2016),(2017,2017)] it is working but i don't want to write hard code. How can i solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, i don't need to create a new method and can use like;

```py
year = fields.Selection([(num, str(num)) for num in range(1900, (datetime.now().year)+1 )],string='Year', default=datetime.now().year)
```

Thanks.